# How to get an array of document properties from a TreeNode?

Tags: c#, kentico

Is it possible to get an array/list of document properties from a Kentico `TreeNode` object?

My use case is I would like to write a class that wraps a custom Document Type. This class will have a method that outputs a formatted string that includes values entered by the user in the CMSDesk.

If I know the name of the property in advance I can do the following:

```
(TreeNode)node.GetValue("Key");
```

However, because properties could be added or removed from the Document Type in the CMS Site Manager, I don't want to hard code any strings in the class.

Instead, I'd like to access them kind of like this:

```
string[] keys = (TreeNode)node.GetKeys();
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(string key in keys)
{
  dictionary.Add(key, node.GetValue(key));
}
```

I don't see a method on the `TreeNode` object that would give me the data I'm looking for--is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might depend on if you are creating a new `TreeNode` or retrieving it from the Content Tree.

If you are using `SelectSingleNode` or `SelectNodes` to populate your `node` object than `node.ColumnNames` will give you a list of all the columns/fields that come back with that node's class.

```
foreach (string column in node.ColumnNames)
{
     //do something helpful with each one
     string value = ValidationHelper.GetString(node.GetValue(column), string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: So simple and yet I didn't see that in my intellisense.  This is exactly what I needed, thank you friend!